# Angular 10 : Remove this use of the output from "getTableStat"; "getTableStat" doesn't return anything

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube

i get this message error :Remove this use of the output from "getTableStat"; "getTableStat" doesn't return anything

```
loadPage() {
const tableStat: any = this.getTableStat();
this.sortColumn = tableStat?.sortColumn;
this.sortDirection = tableStat?.sortDirection;
this.selection.clear();
}

private getTableStat(): void {
return isDefined(this.tableStat)
  ? this.tableService.getStat(this.tableStat)
  : null;
}
```

please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: `private getTableStat(): void {` return type void, means return nothing, maybe adjust your function a bit. to actually tell what it returns

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting it to return tableStat (assuming it is defined??) then the return Type should be whatever type that tableStat is (preferably NOT < any >).

The following sets an interface for the expected structure of the  TableStat type (I just made it up based on the two variables you mentioned - not knowing what the full structure actually is) and then uses that as the return type from the method that gets the tableStat.

also - not knowing the code - but unless isDefined(...) is in the global space  - you may need it to be this.isDefined(...) which can also be a source of the data being undefined.

```
export interface TableStat {
  sortColumn: string;
  sortDirection: string;
}

... 

private getTableStat(): TableStat{
return isDefined(this.tableStat)
  ? this.tableService.getStat(this.tableStat)
  : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have bad code in more lines there:

-1) you said to your method `getTableStat` to return nothing (declaring the return type as `void`), but inside your method you return a null value or call another function `this.tableService.getStat(this.tableStat)` which probably will return some data. So, I'm almost sure you need to change the return type of your `getTableStat` method;

-2) inside `loadPage` you use getTableStat response to declare a constant, but due of 1st step (your method returning nothing), you get the error;

Even if is not recommandating, you can declare the type to `any` instead of `void` and probably will solve this issue (or just remove the `void` type and the compiler will detect automatically the data):

```
private getTableStat(): any {
   //
}
```

*If your service `getStats` returns an Observable, you need to do some more changes there because you'll need to subscribe to it*

How I'll do this:

```
loadPage(): void {
  this.getTableStat().subscribe(stats => {
    if (typeof stats === 'undefined') {
      return;
    }

    this.sortColumn = stats.sortColumn;
    this.sortDirection = stats.sortDirection;
    this.selection.clear();
  });
}

private getTableStat(): Observable<yourDataType | undefined> {
  return isDefined(this.tableStat)
    ? this.tableService.getStat(this.tableStat)
    : of(undefined); // of is an RxJS operator
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. it's working for me